# Why do I get "package does not exist" error when I run maven install?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, package, pom.xml

After running the `maven clean`,
when I run the `maven install` command, I get several `package ... does not exist` errors for the imports.

However, I checked, and the packages do exist, and they are there, under the "Maven Dependencies" folder. With the F3 shortcut, I can open the declaration also, and read the source code.

The Eclipse's code syntax check does not show any error.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Is those dependencies are in your POM file?

Comment: Which are the packages that are marked as non-existing ?

Comment: can you show us the pom file and the errors you are getting?

Comment: Thank you guys, Aaron Digulla's solution worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common cause for this is that you're mixing `compile` and `test` scope. Check the scope of your dependency (`test` scoped deps are gray in the Dependency View). Those dependencies are not available for code under `src/main/java/`.

Comment: You are totally right. I deployed the source code from src/main/java to src/test/java, and now it works.
Thank you!

Comment: Worthy to specifically state: Eclipse cannot differentiate between compile and test scope (still!) and thus all dependencies go on one big pile; Maven -does- split those into isolated classpaths. So if you make the mistake of using test-scoped dependencies or classes in your main source files, then you can get this problem.

Comment: HOW do I get the Dependency view in Eclipse STS ? I am guessing its the same for all Eclipse Java IDEs.